# Problema em um foreach

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, foreach, laravel-blade

Estou utilizando *Laravel 5.3*, e ao fazer um `foreach` na view, ele não reconhece como objeto, porem se eu imprimo somente o que está na variável `$user` ele imprime um objeto `json`.

*Controller:*

```
public function getAll()
{
    return view('user.index',
        [
            'data' => $this->user->all(),
            'nav' => $this->nav
        ]
    );
}
```

*Blade:*

```
@foreach($data as $user)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{$user->id}}</td>
        <td class="text-center"><a href="/users/detalhes/{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</a></td>
        <td class="text-center">{{$user->email}}</td> //essa é a linha que acusa o erro
        <td class="text-center"><a href="/empresas/detalhes/{{$user->empresa->id}}">{{$user->empresa->razao_social}}</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

*Erro:*

> ErrorException in bd796ee4ce7ef1a15a679338ab7787ec13bf0e7d.php line 34:
>   Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\dev\comercio\controlnet\resources\views\user\index.blade.php)

---

Alguém conseguiu encontrar o erro?

Comment: Não programo PHP, tampouco conheço o Laravel, mas, faz sentido usar somente **`$data`** na view? Se você printar `$data` qual é o resultado?

Comment: Eu creio que o erro esteja na verdade na linha seguinte (`{{$user->empresa->razao_social}}`)...pois é impossível, a menos que você tenha sobrescrito o método `all()`, você ter essa informação dessa forma. Você teria que fazer um `join` ou uma outra consulta separada na tabela de empresa pra ter essa informação.

Comment: @jbueno, essa é a magia do `Laravel`, tudo que ele passa no segundo parâmetro do método `view()` é "transformado" em variáveis no 'blade', que é um 'smart' evoluido...

Comment: Ah, sim. Obrigado @KennyRafael. Eu pensei que fosse necessário alguma *keyword* (**`Model`** `.$data`, por exemplo) pra acessar isso.

Comment: @KennyRafael descobri o problema kkkk, é que alguns registros vem sem empresa, então o laravel tenta pegar um objeto que nao existe, mas funciona sim, estou usando empresa como um metodo belongs_to, mas valeu a ajuda ^^

Comment: ah entendi...pelo menos acertei a linha...hahahaha

Comment: @KennyRafael haha boa :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, alguns usuários estão sem empresa, então o método empresa que tem um `belongs_to` com usuário as vezes retorna vazio, portanto não vem as propriedades de `empresa`.

*Resolvi com a seguinte condicional na view:*

```
@if($user->empresa)
    <td class="text-center"><a href="/empresas/detalhes/{{$user->empresa->id}}">{{$user->empresa->razao_social}}</a></td>
@else
    <td class="text-center">
        <strong>Sem empresa</strong>
    </td>
@endif
```

Answer (score 4):

Sei que você já postou uma resposta, mas uma outra solução legal no Laravel seria utilizando o `or` na expressão desejada:

```
{!! $user->empresa->razao_social or "Sem empresa" !!}
```

Comment: Gostei da solução, mas da maneira que eu utilizei eu posso usar uma classe css ou tag html, mesmo escrevendo um pouco mais de código ^^

Comment: @FelipePaetzold foi só um complemento mesmo. É útil fazer como eu fiz em casos de tabelas. Aí você pode botar um valor quando a expressão `or` avaliar a primeira sentença como inválida